# I can't find the problem to this web-scraping script

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I don't really script but I have basic knowledge of what and what not I should do, however, I have run into a problem.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/stocks/dxc"
page = requests.get(URL)

results = soup.find("span", class_="symbol-page-header__pricing-price")

print(results)
```

This gives off neither an error nor success, I don't know what to do.

Comment: This code does not define what 'soup' is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define `soup`. Also include headers in your request to emulate a browser, otherwise the site won't load:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/stocks/dxc"
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.142 Safari/537.36'}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content)
results = soup.find("span", class_="symbol-page-header__pricing-price")

print(results)
```

PS. you will probably not get the data you want this way, as the site loads the data dynamically via the nasdaq api. You could use `Selenium` for scraping, or - better - directly call the api.